# How to compare columns after getting the duplicate records in sql?

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a column with ID containing duplicates of the same value, how can I then first get the rows of values which are same for that column and then compare the other fields.

For example, in the below table if I can multiple occurrences of id firstly let's say 5 and then compare st date and enddate of same id values like (st date of 1st column <= EndDate of 2nd column) and (st date of 2nd column <= EndDate of 1 st column). I've tried figuring it out but to no avail. please help.

```
st date | enddate|  id   | date
   123  |  657   | 5      | 20 dec
   123  |  658   | 2      | Null
   124  |  543   | 5      | Null
   124  |  544   | 3333   | 1 Feb
   125  |  098   | 4444   | Null
   125  |  065   | 4444   | Null
```

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. hope it makes sense.

Comment: See? Futile. :-(